# Does A SSL Certificate Need to be Purchased and Setup for OpenVPN?

Tags: vps, openvpn

I'm planning on setting up OpenVPN on a Cloud Server from Rackspace Cloud. Does a SSL certificate need to be purchased and setup manually for OpenVPN? What about Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 2):

No.  There exist many good writeups on creating your own CA for OpenVPN purposes, plus mine, which is at http://www.teaparty.net/technotes/home-wireless.html#OpenVPN .